# How to make square button with side equal 1/3 of another button width

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i have two buttons. One of them in the bottom on the screen and change its width on different screen sizes. How to link width of second button to make it as 1/3 of first button width. Thanx

Comment: You should try with Autolayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autolayout -> `Ctrl-drag` from button to other button in Interface Builder -> Select `Equal Width` -> change factor to `1/3` (or 3 depending on how the constraint is connected).